# Express interest in/toward/to something

Tags: prepositions

Which is correct and which is colloquial or incorrect of the three choices?

- Does your son express interest **in** music?
- Does your son express interest **toward** music?
- Does your son express interest **to** music?

I would certainly use "in", but what about the other options?

Comment: @user3169 I did a search for "interest toward" and "interest to", both returned good results.

Comment: @user3169 And I was speaking about "interest" in general, so it's not "an interest", you are wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Interest in** can refer to a desire to learn something or a desire to engage in an activity or behavior.

> Their dog showed very little interest in food, so they knew something was wrong.
>
> Has your child shown any interest in joining a sports team?
>
> Does he have any interest in auto repair?

**Interest to**  can refer to a claim of ownership in something.

> She has an interest to a valuable property on Main Street.

**Interest toward** can refer to an intention or purpose.

> The city council has raised the parking tax by 30% with an interest toward reducing traffic congestion downtown.

Answer (score 3):

The usage of **interest(ed) in** and **interest(ed) to** was outlined by user Egghead99 in [this helpful answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/32998/interested-in-to-whats-the-difference).

> **"Interested in"** is used when what comes after it is a noun, or a verb acting like a noun (known as a gerund). [...] Therefore, this sentence usually takes the form *"[Someone] is **interested in** [something]."*
>
> **"Interested to"** is used when what comes after it is a verb in its "to
>   form" (known as an infinitive). [...] This type of sentence usually takes the form of "*[Someone] is **interested** [**to** do something].*"

**Interest(ed) towards**, however, is a bit tricky. [It has consistently been unpopular and rarely used throughout all periods, according to Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=interest+towards&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinterest%20towards%3B%2Cc0). Therefore, it is not by any measures colloquial. In the few cases where it was used, the word **toward** does not seem to accompany **interest** itself, but rather other constructions, such as [**direct** (towards)](https://books.google.com/books?id=3GCAAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA95&dq=%22interest%20towards%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJuqLy8pbdAhXLM48KHUU9BY0Q6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22interest%20towards%22&f=false) and [**turned** (towards)](https://books.google.com/books?id=Qrk5dMMQyY0C&pg=PA19&dq=%22interest%20towards%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJuqLy8pbdAhXLM48KHUU9BY0Q6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=%22interest%20towards%22&f=false). [In one case](https://books.google.com/books?id=YVJpAAAAMAAJ&q=%22interest%20towards%22&dq=%22interest%20towards%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJuqLy8pbdAhXLM48KHUU9BY0Q6AEISDAG), **interest toward** seem to have been used exclusively to avoid repetition. In some other cases, like [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=uxV9AAAAMAAJ&q=%22interest%20towards%22&dq=%22interest%20towards%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihh7zL9JbdAhUJtY8KHajvDig4ChDoAQgpMAE) and [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=y2ghAQAAMAAJ&q=%22interest%20towards%22&dq=%22interest%20towards%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihh7zL9JbdAhUJtY8KHajvDig4ChDoAQglMAA), **interest(ed) towards** is used in some situations where it is effectively interchangeable with **interest(ed) in**.

To sum it up, you are **interested in something**, **interested to do something**, but most likely *won't be* **interested towards something**.

Comment: The is it right to say "I would like to express my interest to participate in the selection process for the position of ‘Data Scientist’"?

Answer (score 0):

"Does your son express interest in music?" - this is the correct and most common option, a mere inquiry about your son's attitude.

"Does your son express interest toward music?" - as "toward" is the preposition showing direction of movement (not especially physical movement!), this expression is not grammatically incorrect, but it has a strong implication that your son hasn't been interested in music before (or is not expected to be interested in music).

"Does your son express interest to music?" - I believe, it isn't grammatically correct. Please, note, that I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: Thank you Yuliya, but since you are not a native speaker, maybe you could add some authoritative references to prove your position?